# TCP/IP communication between Matlab and C++

Tags: c++, matlab, tcp

I have problem in TCP/IP communication between Matlab and C++. I create a server in C++ using `MWinsock`, that can send and receive data from client. In Matlab (acts as client), I create TCP/IP object, connect to server, and use `fprintf` to send a text to server [for example, I send text "A005" to server, `fprintf(t, 'A005')`]. However, on server run in C++ just receive sometime empty text '' or only '05' or 'A0', sometimes is 'A005'. So, could anyone give some help on this problem, many thanks!

---

Thank you for your answers,
The codes are actually simple

*In Matlab, use TCP/IP object:

```
t = tcpip('IPaddress', 1200); %IPaddress get from server after running 'winServer.exe' file.
fopen(t);  
fprintf(t, 'A005')
```

*On the server, I use server file developed by LiyangYu (you may download .exe file from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7108/A-light-weighted-client-server-socket-class-in-C)).

I tried and got problem as described above, so could you give any solutions? 
Thank you!

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the code. Could it be that output is buffered (i.e you need to flush)?

Comment: Yeah, let's see the exact code (preferably for both sides). I/O can be fiddly with the details.

Comment: (agree with Amro) Maybe same problem as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846924/payload-split-over-two-tcp-packets-when-using-boost-asio-when-it-fits-within-th ? Please give more details.

Comment: Please try `fprintf( t, 'A005\n');` to encourage a flush.

Comment: @XuanThuongTran: just to be clear, are you using the [`tcpip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip.html) object from the Instrument Control toolbox?

Comment: Hi Armo, that's right, i am using tcpip object from Instrument Control Toolbox. Do you know the reason of my problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Shai: I tried fprintf( t, 'A005\n'); but this time server always receives empty text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually read the code and description of the project you [linked to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7108/A-light-weighted-client-server-socket-class-in-C)? You can't just pick some random code and expect it to work!

This is an example of a basic TCP chat server (poorly programmed if you ask me). It works with messages formatted according to a specific convention:

- message length (6 chars right aligned padded with spaces): `sprintf('%6d',len)`
- followed by actual message string

With that said, here is a simple client in MATLAB to interact with the C++ chat server:

```
%# helper functions to send/receive messages according to the protocol
send = @(t,msg) fwrite(t, [sprintf('%6d',length(msg)) msg], 'uint8');
recv = @(t) char(fread(t, str2double(char(fread(t,6,'uint8')')), 'uint8')');

%# connect to server
t = tcpip('127.0.0.1',1200);
fopen(t);

%# send a message
send(t,'hello there')

%# receive response and display it
m = recv(t);
fprintf('[SERVER]: %s\n', m);

%# send BYE message to disconnect from chat
send(t,'bye')

%# close socket and clear it
fclose(t);
delete(t); clear t
```

Of course the server `winserver.exe` has to be running first in a separate console (don't forget to type your messages in there to respond to client)

Comment: Actually, I read the code and description from codeproject link but I could not see my problem until now. Now, I found it with your useful helps and comments. As you said, that is the mes_header_len = 6, followed by actual message. Thank you very much!